# How to iterate in python using for i in range loop?

Tags: python

I wonder how can I run the code below 4 times in which, in each run the variables in z (which are a and b) takes the new number while c stays the same?

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
print (a)
    
b = [4,5,6,7]
print (b)
    
c = [5]
print (c)

for i in range(4):
  z = (a**2)*b+c
   print (z)
```

The output I am looking for is:

```
9 ---> z = (1**4)*4+5
25---> z = (2**5)*4+5
59---> z = (3**6)*4+5
117---> z = (4**7)*4+5
```

Comment: Well, you need to use `i` somehow. It appears that instead of `a` you need to use `i + 1`, and instead of `**2` you need to use `**(i + 4)`. And you need to define `b` and `c` as numbers, not lists: `b = 4`, `c = 5`.

Comment: Does `c` only ever have length 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for i, j in zip(a, b):
    z = (i**2)*j+c[0]
    print (z)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you get the results on the left side from the calculations on the right. Based on your descriptions, I think what you meant is:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
print(a)

b = [4, 5, 6, 7]
print(b)

c = [5]
print(c)

for i in range(4):
    z = (a[i] ** b[i]) * 4 + c[0]
    print(z)
```

which gives:

```
9 ---> z = (1**4)*4+5
133 ---> z = (2**5)*4+5
2921 ---> z = (3**6)*4+5
65541 ---> z = (4**7)*4+5
```